# Makefile patsubs double replacement

Tags: makefile

is a possible to do something like this, without shell command:

```
CXX_MODULES += $(patsubst %, %/%.cpp, $(LIBRARIES))
```

notice double replacement which does not work (only first replacement happens)

after some tinkering I came up with

```
$(join $(LIBRARIES), $(patsubst %, /%.cpp, $(LIBRARIES)))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your solution, but this also works

```
expand = $(1)/$(1).cpp

CXX_MODULES += $(foreach x, $(LIBRARIES), $(call expand,$(x)))
```